# keep the original value of radio button if the pop-up is not confirmed angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I want to keep the original value of radio button if the pop-up message was not confirmed.

I have a function that display the pop message when the value of the radio button is changed

```
radioChange(event: MatRadioChange) {
    this.dialogConfig = {
        autoFocus: true,
        closeOnNavigation: false,
        width: '695px',
        disableClose: true,

    };
    this.messageDialog.open(MessageDialogComponent, this.dialogConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the previous value on `this`.

```
this.radioButtonValue = false;
```

Then in your radioChange function, you can assign the value you want keep.

```
radioChange(event: MatRadioChange) {

   this.radioButtonValue = MatRadioChange.target.value;

   this.dialogConfig = {
      autoFocus: true,
      closeOnNavigation: false,
      width: '695px',
      disableClose: true,
    };

    this.messageDialog.open(MessageDialogComponent, this.dialogConfig);

}
```

Comment: But the pop-up is in other compenent